# V-icon does not display icon in Vuetify 3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a Laravel 9 application with Vue 2.6 and Vuetify 2. In this application, I use `v-icon` in the following way, and it works.

```
 <v-icon color="black" large @click="closeDialog()">
        mdi-arrow-left
 </v-icon>
```

Also, if I want to append/prepend an icon in a v-text-field or v-textarea, it works

```
 <v-textarea
     v-model.trim="commentText"  
     label="Write a comment.."
     append-icon="mdi-send"
    >
 </v-textarea>
```

I am migrating my application to Laravel 10, Vue 3 and Vuetify 3. In this application, `v-icon` displays nothing. The following displays nothing and I also don't see any errors in console.

```
<v-icon>mdi-cog</v-icon>
<v-icon> mdi-calendar</v-icon>
<v-icon> mdi-access-point </v-icon>
<v-icon> mdi-star </v-icon>
```

As a workaround (after some Google search), I import icons (through @jamescoyle/vue-icon)  and then use it with svg-icon, like this:

```
<v-icon
                    size="36"
                    color="black"
                    large
                >
                    <svg-icon
                        type="mdi"
                        size="36"
                        :path="mdiArrowLeft"
                    ></svg-icon>
                </v-icon>
```

This is my resources/js/app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
 directives,
})


const app = createApp({});

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

//app.mount('#app');  

// Updated to use vuetify
app.use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

My question is: How to make `v-icon` work like it used to work in my Vue-Vuetify 2 application in Vue-Vuetify 3 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Material Design Icons (mdi), you just have to add the right package. Usually, you would use [@mdi/font](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mdi/font), and you would set it up as described in the [documentation for icon fonts](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/):

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'

import 'vuetify/styles'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

const icons = {
  defaultSet: 'mdi',
  aliases,
  sets: {
    mdi,
  }
}

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  icons,
  ... 
})
```

But it works just the same as in Vuetify 2:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

createApp({}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-icon>mdi-cog</v-icon>
    <v-icon> mdi-calendar</v-icon>
    <v-icon> mdi-access-point </v-icon>
    <v-icon> mdi-star </v-icon>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ringer. Thanks. I did npm install @mdi/font --save and after I included the two '<link' statements you have provided in code snippet, most of my icons started working. However, I could not implement it through app.js. (I have updated my original post to show app.js.

Comment: Looks like you are not passing the `icons` configuration object to `createVuetify()`, only components and directives. I have updated the code block to make it more apparent (also I added the two missing import statements for the css, sorry for that!). When you add the `icon` object to `createVuetify()`, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for giving updated code for app.js. (I have found that setting up app.js to use various packages the most challenging). Yes, everything works. I have removed the <link> statements from app.blade.php, and <v-icon> works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is exactly what vuetify documentation suggests, however,I don't have an iconsets directory in my vuretify package. What am I missing here?

Comment: @domjanzsoo The iconsets are not part of Vuetify, you have to install them separately. Check the `@mdi/font` link in the answer

Comment: @MoritzRingler then why is it imported from Vuetify?
`import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi` . I don't have the 'aliases' and 'mdi' modules in the vuetify directory, even though I installed @mdi/font. I installed even @mdi/js as suggested in the documentation. For some reason none of them work for me.

Comment: @domjanzsoo Oh, you mean that mdi. Sorry, yes, that is part of Vuetify, I have an iconsets folder in `node_modules/vuetify/lib/iconsets/`,